# Multiple dynamic selectors in jQuery using variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, jquery-selectors

Using a single dynamic selector I have no problems:

```
var answer_id = <?php echo $answer_id; ?>;

$('#a_flag_' + answer_id).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

         //Ajax etc...
```

But if I add several dynamic selectors they do not work (ie, no errors on Firebug console, but also no action when clicked):

```
var answer_id = <?php echo $answer_id; ?>;

$('#a_flag_' + answer_id,'#a_comments_link_' + answer_id,'#a_best_answer_' + answer_id).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

         //Ajax etc...
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the commas **inside** the quoted constant strings.

```
$('#a_flag_' + answer_id + ', #a_comments_link_' + answer_id + ',  #a_best_answer_' + answer_id).click(// ///
```

What you want to end up with is a string that looks like

```
"selector, selector, selector, ..."
```

so you need to concatenate a bunch of strings with commas.

Alternatively, you could build up your separate selectors in an array of strings and then ".join()" them with a comma separator (the parameter to ".join()").

Answer (score 1):

You should put the coma inside the string not outside and you have forgotten the plus.

```
$('#a_flag_' + answer_id + ', #a_comments_link_' + answer_id +',#a_best_answer_' + answer_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

When it starts to look too complicated, it likely is.
FWIW:

```
var selectors = [
  '#a_flag_' + answer_id,
  '#a_comments_link_' + answer_id
  // etc.
]
$(selectors.join(", ")).click(...)
```

Happy coding.